# Passing an array in PHP to another PHP script through html hidden form element

Tags: php, html

My question is that when I copy my array elements between different php scripts using session variables, nothing gets printed out. The following are my two php files.

file1.php

```
   $SQL = "SELECT * FROM tblquestions";
if ($db_found) {
        $result = mysql_query($SQL);
        $numRows = mysql_num_rows($result); //return number of rows in the table
        echo '<FORM NAME ="form1" METHOD ="POST" ACTION ="file2.php">';
        for ($i = 1; $i <= 2; $i++)
        {
            $db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
            $qID[$i] = $db_field['QID'];
            $question[$i] = $db_field['Question'];
            $A[$i] = $db_field['qA'];
            $B[$i] = $db_field['qB'];
            $C[$i] = $db_field['qC'];
            echo '<P>';
            print $question[$i];
            echo '<P>';
            echo "<INPUT TYPE = 'Radio' Name = '".$qNum."'  value= 'A'>"; 
            print $A[$i];
            echo '<P>';
            echo  "<INPUT TYPE = 'Radio' Name = '".$qNum."'   value= 'B'>"; 
            print $B[$i];
            echo '<P>';
            echo  "<INPUT TYPE = 'Radio' Name = '".$qNum."'   value= 'C'>"; 
            print $C[$i];
            //if (isset($_POST[$name_Value]))
            $survey_Answers[$i-1] = $_POST[$qNum];
            print '</BR>'.$survey_Answers[$i-1]."</BR>";
            $question_Number = ltrim($qNum,'q');
            $question_Number++;
            $qNum ='q'.$question_Number;
        }

        echo '<p>';
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['answers'] = $survey_Answers;
        echo '<INPUT TYPE = "Submit" Name = "Submit1"  VALUE = "Click here to vote">';

        echo '</form>';
```

On my Second file (file2.php), I have the following:

```
<?PHP
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['Submit1'])) {
        $results = $_SESSION['answers'];
        print $results[0];
?>
```

Nothing gets printed out when executing the above code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why aren't you simply saving that to a session variable? Anything in HTML document can be manually modified.

Comment: Not sure if it's a typo in the question, but you're missing an `=` after `value`

Comment: When for the first time you submit the form, //if (isset($_POST[$name_Value]))
            $survey_Answers[$i-1] = $_POST[$qNum];
            print '</BR>'.$survey_Answers[$i-1]."</BR>";
            $question_Number = ltrim($qNum,'q');
            $question_Number++;
            $qNum ='q'.$question_Number; this part works for the first time. so the next time you submit the form, you'll get value for $Survey_answers not on the first time.

You can simply work with the radio input, instead of relying another array.

Comment: do you mean adding a hidden form element in my first for loop. Again, don't I need an array to hold these multiple values as I'm going to use them on another php script.

Comment: @N.B. Maybe that's what he wants to do

Comment: N.B, Pierre, I've tried using session variables but it didn't work for me.

Comment: "It didn't work for me" is exactly like saying "I tried to drive a car but it didn't work for me". What didn't work? There is literally 1 million reasons for something not working. This smells like [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: N.B, it now works for me

Comment: N.B, this works for me on the same script. However, when I try to grab my results in a different php script, it doesn't work.

Comment: N.B, I've modified my above code to reflect the use of sessions variables. However, I'm not able to access these values on file2.php. Am I missing something?

Comment: nothing gets printed when I issue print $results[0];

Comment: Any more help on this? This is my first time on stackoverflow. Should I create another question?

Comment: I would move the session_start(); to the top so that it is issued first thing which is required if you expect session cookies to work.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure that the session values stored need to be strings.

In file1.php change:

```
$_SESSION['answers'] = $survey_Answers;
```

to this:

```
$_SESSION['answers'] = json_encode($survey_Answers);
```

Then in file2.php change:

```
$results = $_SESSION['answers'];
```

to this:

```
$results = json_decode($_SESSION['answers']);
```

Comment: I tried this. However, I modified my action to file1.php. So I typed the following command: echo $_SESSION['answers'][0]; and the output was a square bracket.

Comment: In file1 just after:  $_SESSION['answers'] = json_encode($survey_Answers);  add this line and post the results:  echo var_dump($_SESSION['answers']);

Comment: actually, what is making me crazy is that when I use any other variable that is not Array type. Everything works correctly.

Comment: this is the output of executing the following:  echo var_dump($_SESSION['answers']);                         string '[]' (length=2)

Comment: It looks like the $survey_Answers variable is an empty array.  To confirm, can you do a var_dump($survey_Answers); just above the code $_SESSION['answers'] = json_encode($survey_Answers);

Comment: array (size=2)
  0 => string 'C' (length=1)
  1 => string 'B' (length=1)

string '["C","B"]' (length=9)

Comment: I get the following when I have my actin set to the same file and after hitting the submit button

Comment: Things works fine for me when I use the same file, however, when I post the results to a different php file nothing shows up.

Comment: this is the answer I'm getting at file2.php: string '[]' (length=2). I believe, this seems like my session is not saved which is something I would start dig on. Any other thoughts you can think of?

Comment: Are you able to set a simple session value in file1, such as $_SESSION['testing']='success'; and access it in file 2, echo $_SESSION['testing'];  ?

Comment: Yes, so this seems like not a session problem. I've created some test array and sent it through a session variable with no problem. I'm not sure what else I should be looking for. It seems that my selections for radio buttons are not sent once I hit the submit button. Can't figure out why!!!!!!!

Comment: So instead of an array, I saved my output data from radio buttons to a comma separated string. By changing the form action field to the same script(file1.php) and using a form element of type hidden to send the string and after hitting the submit button, an empty string is printed. However, when I click back on the submit button my string appears.

Comment: Getting hard to follow.  Can you update the code in your question to reflect the current state.

Comment: Check this, It is solved : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17311179/submit-button-needs-to-be-clicked-twice-to-get-my-results-from-radio-buttons-in . However, thank you so much for all your help