# Submit button needs to be clicked twice to get my results from radio buttons in a php script

Tags: php, html

The problem with this code is that I can't read the results in $survey_Answers1 except after clicking on the submit button twice.

file:survey.php

```
<?PHP
session_start();
    //=========================================================
    //The following page is used to create a dynamic survey.
    //=========================================================
    $qNum = 'q1';
    $question = 'Question not set';
    $answerA = 'unchecked';
    $answerB = 'unchecked';
    $answerC = 'unchecked';
    $qID = array();
    $question = array();
    $A = array();
    $B = array();
    $C = array();
    $survey_Answers = array();
    $survey_Answers1 = '';
    //============================================
    //  OPEN A CONNECTION TO THE DATABASE
    //============================================
    $user_name = "root";
    $password = "";
    $database = "surveyTest";
    $server = "127.0.0.1";
    $db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $password);
    $db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);
    $SQL = "SELECT * FROM tblquestions";
    if ($db_found) {
        $result = mysql_query($SQL);
        $numRows = mysql_num_rows($result); //return number of rows in the table
        echo '<FORM NAME ="form1" METHOD ="POST" ACTION ="survey.php">';
        for ($i = 1; $i <= 2; $i++)
        {
            $db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
            $qID[$i] = $db_field['QID'];
            $question[$i] = $db_field['Question'];
            $A[$i] = $db_field['qA'];
            $B[$i] = $db_field['qB'];
            $C[$i] = $db_field['qC'];
            echo '<P>';
            print $question[$i];
            echo '<P>';
            echo "<INPUT TYPE = 'Radio' Name = '".$qNum."'  value= 'A'>"; 
            print $A[$i];
            echo '<P>';
            echo  "<INPUT TYPE = 'Radio' Name = '".$qNum."'   value= 'B'>"; 
            print $B[$i];
            echo '<P>';
            echo  "<INPUT TYPE = 'Radio' Name = '".$qNum."'   value= 'C'>"; 
            print $C[$i];
            if (isset($_POST[$qNum])){
                $survey_Answers1 = $survey_Answers1.', '.$_POST["$qNum"];
            }
            //var_dump($survey_Answers1);
            $question_Number = ltrim($qNum,'q');
            $question_Number++;
            $qNum ='q'.$question_Number;
        }

        echo '<p>';
        //$_SESSION['answers'] = $survey_Answers1;
        //var_dump($_SESSION['answers']);
        echo "<INPUT TYPE = 'hidden' Name = 'h2'  VALUE = '".$survey_Answers1."'>";
        echo '<INPUT TYPE = "Submit" Name = "Submit1"  VALUE = "Click here to vote">';
        var_dump($_POST['h2']);

        echo '</form>';

        mysql_close($db_handle);
    }
    else {
        print "Error getting Survey";
        mysql_close($db_handle);
    }
?>
```

The value stored in var_dump($_POST['h2']); after hitting clicking the submit button once is: string '' (length=0)

P.S., using session variables doesn't resolve the problem, so please don't suggest this answer!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to insert after for-loop

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 2; $i++)
{
   // your code here
}
if (empty($_POST['h2'])) $_POST['h2'] = $survey_Answers1; // insert this line
```

Or use JavaScript, insert to the end of file:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        if ($('form').length > 0) {
            $('form').submit(function(e){
                var answers = '';
                $('input[type=Radio]:checked').each(function() {
                    if (answers !== '') {
                        answers += ',';
                    }
                    answers += $(this).val();
                })
                $('input[name=h2]').val(answers);

            });
        }
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Problem is that at the first request "h2" field would be always empty! If you want to fill this field dinamically, use JavaScript (for example, "change" event in JQuery).

Comment: This works in the same php file. However, when I try to take retrieve the value in $survey_Answers1 in another php script (by setting the action field to a different php script), an empty string is printed. Any ideas?

Comment: I have added JavaScript example to answer. Check it.

Comment: Even thought I didn't yet fully grasped your answer. But it works :). Thank you so much :).

Comment: You should learn JavaScript a bit to understand this fully. Good luck.

Comment: I worked on it long time ago, needs to refresh my memory on it. Again thank you

Answer (score 0):

From what I see your problem is with your for loop try to see whats returning survey_Answers1 in each loop. you can try this to see whats returning each time it loops and part from there

```
if (isset($_POST[$qNum])){
   $survey_Answers1 = $survey_Answers1.', '.$_POST["$qNum"];
?>
   <script type="text/javascript"><?php echo $survey_Answers1; ?></script>
<?php
        }
```